# How do I find out which app is using my Mic?

Tags: macos, privacy, microphone, malware

I'm running MacOS Sonoma 14.2 (23C64).
My command bar looks like this — the orange dot says that the mic is on:
[image]

If I click it, it says that the mic is being used by another user:

[image]

If I click "other user", it claims to be the System Administrator:

[image]

I think that someone has added spyware to my computer.

There are 167 processes running as root.

Here is the root process list:

```
root               628 122.1  0.7 36518400 221160   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:43.72 /Applications/TrendMicro.localized/AFMAgent.app/Contents/Resources/iCoreService.app/Contents/MacOS/iCoreService -p 61301 -n 61100 /Library/Application Support/TrendMicro/common/lib/libTmAntiMalware.dylib
root              1844  84.9  0.9 408596416 310304   ??  Rs    4:40PM   0:10.96 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleNeuralEngine.framework/XPCServices/ANECompilerService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/ANECompilerService
root               437  34.2  0.0 408228032   8560   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:05.17 /System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/backupd-helper -launchd
root               898  25.3  0.1 408319968  47392   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:02.49 /usr/sbin/spindump
root               632  22.6  0.1 35698396  33672   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:45.22 /Library/SystemExtensions/161EA56C-15D0-4F6A-A69B-6A97037B5D8E/com.trendmicro.icore.es.systemextension/Contents/MacOS/com.trendmicro.icore.es
root               404   1.0  0.1 408318912  27248   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:10.73 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Support/tccd system
root               625   0.8  0.1 35764056  25520   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:01.54 /Applications/TrendMicro.localized/AFMAgent.app/Contents/Resources/iCoreService.app/Contents/MacOS/iCoreService -p 61304 -n 61100 /Library/Application Support/TrendMicro/common/lib/libfeedback.dylib /Library/Application Support/TrendMicro/common/lib/libcensus.dylib
root                 1   0.8  0.1 409237936  28560   ??  Ss    4:35PM   0:08.98 /sbin/launchd
root               361   0.6  0.2 408616112  79424   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:05.14 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds
root               337   0.3  0.0 408419024  15488   ??  Ss    4:36PM   3:04.71 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/Support/fseventsd
root               332   0.2  0.1 408469616  48848   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:05.76 /usr/libexec/logd
root               530   0.1  0.0 408548432  12944   ??  S     4:36PM   0:00.07 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ViewBridge.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/ViewBridgeAuxiliary.xpc/Contents/MacOS/ViewBridgeAuxiliary
root               448   0.1  0.1 408320256  48192   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:25.87 /usr/libexec/airportd
root               541   0.1  0.4 411695088 126832   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:02.04 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mds_stores
root              1586   0.0  0.0 409006400  10256   ??  Ss    4:38PM   0:00.04 /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.trendmicro.TrendCleanerPro.HelperTool
root              1558   0.0  0.0 34767856   7860   ??  Ss    4:38PM   0:00.19 /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.tunnelbear.mac.tbeard
root              1528   0.0  0.0 408252992   6704   ??  Ss    4:38PM   0:00.04 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppStoreDaemon.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StorePrivilegedTaskService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StorePrivilegedTaskService
root              1522   0.0  0.0 408120304   6928   ??  Ss    4:38PM   0:00.03 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PackageKit.framework/Resources/system_installd
root              1520   0.0  0.0 408073200   6928   ??  Ss    4:37PM   0:00.04 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PackageKit.framework/Resources/installd
root              1518   0.0  0.0 408301664  12608   ??  Ss    4:37PM   0:00.15 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudKitDaemon.framework/Support/cloudd --system
root              1517   0.0  0.0 409267696   7776   ??  S     4:37PM   0:00.05 /Library/DropboxHelperTools/Dropbox_u501/dbkextd
root              1396   0.0  0.0 408354816   4960   ??  Ss    4:37PM   0:00.05 /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper
root              1375   0.0  0.0 408251952   5456   ??  Ss    4:37PM   0:00.02 /System/Library/Frameworks/CryptoTokenKit.framework/ctkahp.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ctkahp -d
root              1320   0.0  0.0 408128496   4528   ??  Ss    4:37PM   0:00.02 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CacheDelete.framework/deleted_helper
root               901   0.0  0.0 408194592   6512   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.07 /System/Library/CoreServices/SubmitDiagInfo server-init
root              1249   0.0  0.0 35250652  14308   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.40 /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.trendmicro.AFM.HelperTool
root              1226   0.0  0.0 408596288   8624   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.04 /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Resources/bin/simdiskimaged
root              1094   0.0  0.0 408303568  13824   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.07 /System/Library/CoreServices/sharedfilelistd
root               916   0.0  0.0 408702736   5808 s000  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.01 login -fp USERID
root               914   0.0  0.0 408252496   2736   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.03 /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/CVMServer
root               904   0.0  0.0 408301296   9504   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.10 /System/Library/CoreServices/osanalyticshelper server-init
root               896   0.0  0.0 408228864   4928   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.23 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/coresymbolicationd
root               893   0.0  0.0 408301104   9760   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.09 /usr/libexec/wifivelocityd
root               890   0.0  0.0 408200016   5344   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.06 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetCacheServicesExtensions.framework/XPCServices/AssetCacheTetheratorService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/AssetCacheTetheratorService
root               885   0.0  0.0 409664864  12512   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.21 /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/MTLCompilerService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/MTLCompilerService
root               878   0.0  0.0 408324080  13760   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.13 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSSO.framework/Support/AppSSODaemon
root               868   0.0  0.0 408307632  11984   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.15 /usr/libexec/mobileactivationd
root               844   0.0  0.0 408301952  11824   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.04 /usr/libexec/findmydeviced
root               820   0.0  0.0 408130736   4752   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.02 automountd
root               810   0.0  0.0 408104992   5664   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.01 /usr/libexec/wallpaperexportd
root               809   0.0  0.0 409929392  11984   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.34 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TVIdleServices.framework/idleassetsd
root               801   0.0  0.0 408085808   5216   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.01 /System/Library/CoreServices/ReportCrash daemon
root               789   0.0  0.0 408527952   2096   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.01 /usr/libexec/online-auth-agent
root               788   0.0  0.0 408302480   9552   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.55 /usr/libexec/aned
root               782   0.0  0.0 408301680   6912   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:03.01 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XprotectFramework.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/XprotectService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/XprotectService
root               768   0.0  0.0 408315920  13216   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.14 /usr/sbin/filecoordinationd
root               766   0.0  0.0 408285296   7984   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.03 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/Support/awdd
root               714   0.0  0.1 409794000  25568   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.08 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XprotectFramework.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/XProtectBridgeService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/XProtectBridgeService
root               712   0.0  0.0 408092736   3120   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.01 /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/PlugInLibraryService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/PlugInLibraryService
root               673   0.0  0.0 408224768   7008   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.03 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreKDL.framework/Support/corekdld
root               667   0.0  0.1 409954176  42928   ??  S     4:36PM   0:00.49 /Applications/Solarwinds Discovery Agent.app/Contents/Resources/agent/ruby/bin/SamanageAgentSrv /Applications/Solarwinds Discovery Agent.app/Contents/Resources/agent/src/mini_kernel/child_process.rb
root               664   0.0  0.0 408205392   4608   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.03 /usr/libexec/securityd_service
root               663   0.0  0.0 408292672  12896   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.08 /System/Library/Frameworks/LocalAuthentication.framework/Support/coreauthd
root               659   0.0  0.0 408253616   8768   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.04 /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Helpers/GSSCred
root               657   0.0  0.0 408270480   4608   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.02 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountPolicy.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.AccountPolicyHelper.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.AccountPolicyHelper
root               654   0.0  0.0 408292784  15184   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.20 /usr/libexec/rtcreportingd
root               648   0.0  0.0 408258224  11360   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:00.14 /usr/libexec/audioanalyticsd
root               647   0.0  0.0 34641640   8964   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.23 /Library/SystemExtensions/3C03CE64-35D0-45CA-BB76-5896D846E768/com.trendmicro.icore.netfilter.systemextension/Contents/MacOS/com.trendmicro.icore.netfilter
root               646   0.0  0.0 408675808   7920   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.17 /usr/libexec/audioclocksyncd
root               642   0.0  0.0 408241168   9152   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.04 /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioComponentRegistrar -daemon
root               634   0.0  0.0 408524224   5184   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.02 /usr/libexec/cryptexd
root               627   0.0  0.1 35761528  19424   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.68 /Applications/TrendMicro.localized/AFMAgent.app/Contents/Resources/iCoreService.app/Contents/MacOS/iCoreService -p 61100 -n 61100 /Library/Application Support/TrendMicro/common/lib/libnamingService.dylib /Library/Application Support/TrendMicro/common/lib/libtaskManager.dylib /Library/Application Support/TrendMicro/common/lib/libnotificationService.dylib /Library/Application Support/TrendMicro/common/lib/libTmUpdate.dylib /Library/Application Support/TrendMicro/common/lib/libTmDb.dylib
root               630   0.0  0.1 409555664  30976   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.11 /Applications/Solarwinds Discovery Agent.app/Contents/Resources/agent/ruby/bin/ruby /Applications/Solarwinds Discovery Agent.app/Contents/Resources/agent/src/mini_kernel/service_osx.rb
root               631   0.0  0.1 35782152  22108   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.98 /Applications/TrendMicro.localized/AFMAgent.app/Contents/Resources/iCoreService.app/Contents/MacOS/iCoreService -p 61201 -n 61100 /Library/Application Support/TrendMicro/common/lib/libTmProxy.dylib
root               622   0.0  0.0 408098816   7472   ??  R     4:36PM   0:00.05 /usr/sbin/systemstats --logger-helper /private/var/db/systemstats
root               621   0.0  0.0 408318768  11792   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.05 /usr/sbin/systemsoundserverd
root               620   0.0  0.0 408206048   3200   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.06 /usr/libexec/sysmond
root               606   0.0  0.0 408303568  13616   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.89 /usr/libexec/gamepolicyd
root               605   0.0  0.0 408228608   8512   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:00.55 /Library/Apple/System/Library/CoreServices/XProtect.app/Contents/XPCServices/XProtectPluginService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/XProtectPluginService
root               452   0.0  0.0 408194512   6560   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.06 /usr/libexec/usbd
root               560   0.0  0.0 408229040   7520   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.17 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.MobileSoftwareUpdate.CleanupPreparePathService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.MobileSoftwareUpdate.CleanupPreparePathService
root               556   0.0  0.0 408305456  11488   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.12 /usr/libexec/symptomsd-diag
root               553   0.0  0.0 408202560   4512   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.05 /usr/libexec/rpcsvchost -launchd netlogon.bundle
root               542   0.0  0.0 408169808   8656   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.03 /usr/sbin/BTLEServer
root               538   0.0  0.0 408102992   5328   ??  S     4:36PM   0:00.02 /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.hiservices-xpcservice.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.hiservices-xpcservice
root               537   0.0  0.1 408344416  29200   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:03.59 /usr/libexec/searchpartyd
root               536   0.0  0.0 408301600  14464   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.09 /usr/libexec/wifianalyticsd
root               534   0.0  0.1 408153520  19328   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.21 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SiriInference.framework/Support/siriinferenced
root               533   0.0  0.0 408273840  10432   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.02 /usr/libexec/bootinstalld
root               532   0.0  0.0 408238912   9616   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:00.05 /System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/backupd
root               529   0.0  0.0 408269024   8848   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.17 /usr/libexec/securityd_system
root               526   0.0  0.0 408110080   6640   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.01 /usr/libexec/countryd
root               523   0.0  0.0 408261792   9056   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.02 /System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app/Contents/Resources/suhelperd
root               516   0.0  0.0 408302256  16288   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.25 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackgroundTaskManagement.framework/Resources/backgroundtaskmanagementd -daemon
root               514   0.0  0.0 408268752   6608   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.29 /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.CodeSigningHelper.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.CodeSigningHelper
root               512   0.0  0.0 408258992   6432   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.03 /usr/libexec/colorsyncd
root               511   0.0  0.0 408094688   4176   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.01 /System/Library/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.ColorSyncXPCAgent.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.ColorSyncXPCAgent
root               510   0.0  0.0 408302944  12320   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.08 /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemExtensions.framework/Versions/A/Helpers/sysextd
root               509   0.0  0.0 408301120  12320   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.07 /usr/libexec/findmybeaconingd
root               508   0.0  0.0 408301536  10608   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.07 /usr/sbin/WirelessRadioManagerd
root               506   0.0  0.0 408302304  14336   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.10 /usr/libexec/nesessionmanager
root               505   0.0  0.0 408260784   9776   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.01 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WiFiPolicy.framework/XPCServices/WiFiCloudAssetsXPCService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/WiFiCloudAssetsXPCService
root               503   0.0  0.0 408268272   6096   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.02 /usr/libexec/colorsync.displayservices
root               502   0.0  0.1 408323200  43120   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:32.70 /usr/libexec/syspolicyd
root               500   0.0  0.1 408312416  18128   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:01.13 /usr/libexec/storagekitd
root               499   0.0  0.1 408224032  18864   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.28 /usr/libexec/wifip2pd
root               496   0.0  0.0 408301760  11024   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.06 /usr/sbin/mDNSResponderHelper
root               491   0.0  0.2 408319312  52912   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:13.46 /usr/libexec/mobileassetd
root               497   0.0  0.0 408874496  11424   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.07 /usr/libexec/containermanagerd_system --runmode=privileged --user-container-mode=current --bundle-container-mode=global --bundle-container-owner=_appinstalld --system-container-mode=none
root               482   0.0  0.0 408102976   3296   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.01 /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/PlugInLibraryService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/PlugInLibraryService
root               465   0.0  0.0 408185264   5456   ??  S     4:36PM   0:00.10 /usr/sbin/distnoted agent
root               475   0.0  0.0 408303360  14720   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.22 /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/authd.xpc/Contents/MacOS/authd
root               467   0.0  0.0 408091616   3536   ??  S     4:36PM   0:00.01 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/csnameddatad.xpc/Contents/MacOS/csnameddatad
root               466   0.0  0.0 408293584   9696   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.06 /usr/libexec/secinitd
root               464   0.0  0.0 408130080   4848   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.01 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/PerfPowerTelemetryClientRegistrationService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/PerfPowerTelemetryClientRegistrationService
root               456   0.0  0.0 408301888  12608   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.07 /usr/libexec/biometrickitd --launchd
root               451   0.0  0.0 408301712  10976   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.08 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemStatusServer.framework/Support/systemstatusd
root               450   0.0  0.0 408306688  10304   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.09 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAccessories.framework/Support/accessoryd
root               449   0.0  0.0 408301216  13776   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.36 /usr/libexec/nehelper
root               446   0.0  0.0 408120880   4736   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.04 /usr/libexec/apfsd
root               462   0.0  0.0 408233520   8032   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.05 /usr/libexec/trustdFileHelper
root               440   0.0  0.1 408302432  22272   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.17 /usr/libexec/PowerUIAgent
root               441   0.0  0.1 408317376  31936   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:01.14 /usr/libexec/lsd runAsRoot
root               418   0.0  0.1 408311248  22128   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:00.36 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetContext.framework/Resources/contextstored
root               408   0.0  0.0 408292400  14384   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.28 /System/Library/CoreServices/coreservicesd
root               405   0.0  0.1 408304784  20784   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:03.99 /usr/libexec/runningboardd
root               403   0.0  0.0 408059632   1264   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.00 aslmanager
root               401   0.0  0.0 408271152  11184   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:03.20 /usr/sbin/cfprefsd daemon
root               399   0.0  0.0 408243968   5936   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.19 /usr/libexec/logd_helper
root               347   0.0  0.0 408195648   6080   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.02 /usr/libexec/IOMFB_bics_daemon
root               340   0.0  0.0 408505968   3680   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.02 /Library/Apple/System/Library/CoreServices/XProtect.app/Contents/MacOS/XProtect
root               391   0.0  0.0 408269248   6800   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.71 /usr/libexec/usermanagerd -t 15
root               387   0.0  0.0 408063440   1056   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.03 /usr/libexec/dirhelper
root               386   0.0  0.1 408310784  29408   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:04.33 /usr/libexec/PerfPowerServices
root               389   0.0  0.0 408267040   9776   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.18 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/Versions/A/Support/revisiond
root               382   0.0  0.1 408304512  23888   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:01.94 /usr/libexec/dasd
root               367   0.0  0.1 408326784  27504   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:08.07 /usr/libexec/coreduetd
root               368   0.0  0.0 408228208   2048   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.12 /usr/sbin/syslogd
root               374   0.0  0.1 408305568  18640   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:03.66 /System/Library/CoreServices/launchservicesd
root               338   0.0  0.1 408309984  20480   ??  Rs    4:36PM   0:00.32 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/Support/mediaremoted
root               341   0.0  0.0 408284016  15056   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.31 /usr/sbin/systemstats --daemon
root               398   0.0  0.1 408300960  28160   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.24 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMediaIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/com.apple.cmio.registerassistantservice
root               345   0.0  0.0 408302560  14864   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.27 endpointsecurityd
root               333   0.0  0.0 408301104   6256   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.07 /usr/libexec/smd
root               390   0.0  0.0 408085488   3040   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.01 /usr/sbin/KernelEventAgent
root               388   0.0  0.0 408137216   6896   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.03 /System/Library/CoreServices/logind
root               395   0.0  0.0 408304592  10624   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.93 /usr/libexec/sandboxd
root               393   0.0  0.1 408376464  39776   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:02.16 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
root               396   0.0  0.1 408301520  24592   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.88 /usr/libexec/corebrightnessd --launchd
root               397   0.0  0.0 408310880  15968   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.15 /usr/libexec/AirPlayXPCHelper
root               385   0.0  0.0 408170032   5968   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.02 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleCredentialManager.framework/AppleCredentialManagerDaemon
root               377   0.0  0.0 408305520  14576   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:01.21 /usr/sbin/securityd -i
root               371   0.0  0.0 408260048   5264   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.05 /usr/libexec/thermalmonitord
root               372   0.0  0.1 408327616  29456   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:22.33 /usr/libexec/opendirectoryd
root               381   0.0  0.0 408209376   4048   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.01 autofsd
root               373   0.0  0.1 408391120  29728   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:03.37 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/apsd
root               363   0.0  0.1 408307328  23792   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.77 /usr/libexec/kernelmanagerd
root               364   0.0  0.0 408301136   7312   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.35 /usr/libexec/diskarbitrationd
root               360   0.0  0.0 408139008   8048   ??  RNs   4:36PM   0:00.06 /usr/libexec/warmd
root               357   0.0  0.0 408095792   4912   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.02 /usr/libexec/watchdogd
root               354   0.0  0.0 408235520   4224   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.01 /usr/libexec/keybagd -t 15
root               394   0.0  0.0 408268560   6464   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:02.28 /usr/sbin/notifyd
root               352   0.0  0.0 408382304   6880   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.06 /usr/libexec/remoted
root               346   0.0  0.0 408302960  14464   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.74 /System/Library/CoreServices/powerd.bundle/powerd
root               344   0.0  0.0 408307232  15568   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:01.21 /usr/libexec/configd
root               336   0.0  0.0 408067536   4752   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.02 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Uninstall.framework/Resources/uninstalld
root               350   0.0  0.0 408301488  10960   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:02.69 /usr/libexec/amfid
root               334   0.0  0.1 408303552  22576   ??  Ss    4:36PM   0:00.54 /usr/libexec/UserEventAgent (System)
root              1025   0.0  0.0        0      0   ??  Z     4:36PM   0:00.00 <defunct>
root              1888   0.0  0.0 408899520   2688 s000  R+    4:40PM   0:00.00 ps auxww
root              1701   0.0  0.0 408269360  13968   ??  Ss    4:39PM   0:00.33 /usr/libexec/triald_system
```

How do I figure out which application or user or process is using my Mac’s  microphone?

Comment: In the Privacy & Security settings, see which apps are allowed to access the microphone. Quit them one at a time and see what happens.

Comment: Do you have any other admin accounts on this Mac?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the app that's listening to my microphone is the Rogue Amoeba audio driver, for Rogue Amoeba's Sound Source program.

I found this out using [OverSight](https://objective-see.org/products/oversight.html), an amazing privacy tool that I highly recommend (now).

It gives me great alerts like this:

[image]

Comment: That’s a great tool. I’ve also been impressed by [Micro Snitch as well](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/micro-snitch/id972028355?mt=12) over the years. https://obdev.at/products/microsnitch/index.html

Comment: @bmike — if you want to provide Micro Snitch as an answer, I'll upvote it and select it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the GitHub issues for Oversight, it seems it may not work as well as we paranoid folks might prefer!  Little Snitch has similar complaints, but they are all more than a year old.  The new ones are OK but they are few.